Use assembled jar in integration tests
I created an uber jar with the sbt-assembly plugin in one module. Now I would like to use that jar in another sbt module for integration testing. Namely, I need to mount the jar inside a docker testcontainer. Is this possible?

If you set the name of the assembly jar, then referencing it on the other project using a hardcoded string should be easy.
